# How does create_async behave on the UI thread?

Tags: uwp, task, c++-cx, ppl

Let's say I have a function that I call on the UI thread:

```
IAsyncOperation<BitmapImage^>^ GetImage()
{
    return create_async([]
    {
        return create_task(GetStreamAsync())
            .then([] (Stream^ stream)
        {
            auto image = ref new BitmapImage();
            // set image properties.
            image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            return image;
        });
    });
}
```

I know the inner task will also execute on the UI thread since [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134704/when-does-a-ppl-task-execute-on-the-ui-thread) indicates an apartment aware task continues in its apartment by default.

But when is the execution of the create_task body scheduled? Does it end up happening synchronously? Or does the UI thread wait until it has free cycles to process the async logic?

Comment: C++/CX (borrowed from C++/CLI ECMA 372) is a different language than C++ (ISO/IEC 14882:2017).  Should not have the 'c++' tag.  Sort of like Java and JavaScript are two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find out:

```
void ShowThread(std::string caller)
{
  std::string result{ caller + ": Current thread is " };
  result = result + std::to_string(GetCurrentThreadId());
  result = result + "\r\n";

  OutputDebugStringA(result.c_str());
}

using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem^>^ GetFile()
{
  ShowThread("GetFile");
  return create_async([]
  {
    ShowThread("Inside create_async");
    return create_task(
      ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->TryGetItemAsync(L"foo"))
      .then([](IStorageItem^ item)
      {
        ShowThread("Inside .then");
        return item;
    });
  });
}

MainPage::MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  GetFile();
}
```

This shows something like this:

```
GetFile: Current thread is 34100
Inside create_async: Current thread is 34100
Inside .then: Current thread is 34100
```

You can see they're all on the same thread - `create_async` calls its argument immediately (it doesn't schedule it as a task) and simply converts the return value to an `IAsyncOperation<T>`. If you want the continuation to **not** be on the UI thread, you can do this:

```
    return create_task(
      ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->TryGetItemAsync(L"foo"))
      .then([](IStorageItem^ item)
    {
      ShowThread("Inside .then");
      return item;
    }, task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary());
```

Then PPL will run the continuation on an arbitrary thread.